# Interpreting unsigned integers as signed while widening

Tags: haskell, integer

Suppose I've got a lot of values of type `Word8`, `Word16`, and `Word32` lying around. I want to widen them, interpreting some as signed and some as unsigned, so that I can store them all in an `[Int64]`. I know I can write something like the following function, where the first argument specifies whether we want to interpret the `Word8` as signed or not:

```
convert8 :: Bool -> Word8 -> Int64
convert8 False i = fromIntegral i
convert8 True  i = fromIntegral (fromIntegral i :: Int8)
```

This gives me the result I want:

```
*Main> convert8 False 128
128
*Main> convert8 True 128
-128
```

The double `fromIntegral` feels inelegant to me, though. Is there some nicer way to say "interpret this `Word` as a signed integer and stick it in a bigger `Int`"?

Comment: Is there some problem with `convert8 True = negate . fromIntegral`?

Comment: Well, yes, because I don't want negation—I want the unsigned integer to be interpreted as signed, which means e.g. that `convert8 True 1 == 1`.

Comment: But I thought that `convert True` means you want a negative value... such a confusing design!  What you want is a negative value IF the boolean is `True` AND the value would be negative were the word a negative when using a signed type (i.e. out of range for the signed type's positive values)?

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear—the problem is that `Data.Binary.Get` gives me values of type `WordN`, and I know (from my format spec) that some of them should be interpreted as signed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I recall, GHC stores all integers as one machine word. (In other words, a 32-bit GHC stores integers as 32 bits. A 64-bit GHC stores them as 64 bits.) So if you request an 8-bit integer, it stores it as 32 bits anyway, but only *uses* the first 8 bits.

Because of this, I'm fairly sure that widening or narrowing using `fromIntegral` is actually no-op at run-time; all it does is change the type signature, with no run-time cost. (Converting from unsigned to signed might be doing sign extension, however. I'm not completely sure how that part works. It's probably still one machine instruction though.)

In short, I think the double `fromIntegral` is probably about the best way to do this. You could manually implement sign extension yourself, but the built-in machine instruction for doing this is likely to be faster.